# Installed project-specific nuget packages not being recognized

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I have a web project that won't build because of a nuget error.

We have many websites that all use a web CMS called Sitecore. Our different websites work under different versions. Thus, we have a common library that targets many versions [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25430977/2283050).

So, I have a project structure like seen below. Please keep in mind this is a *logical* representation. Consider all these files being at the root of the solution.

- Common.sln

  - Common.SC65.csproj

    - MyClass.cs [shared]
    - MyClass.SC65.cs
    - **packages.Common.SC65.config**
  - Common.SC70.csproj

    - MyClass.cs [shared]
    - MyClass.SC70.cs
    - **packages.Common.SC70.config**
  - Common.SC72.csproj

    - MyClass.cs [shared]
    - MyClass.SC72.cs
    - **packages.Common.SC72.config**

This is the error I'm having now:

> C:\Path\Website.ProjectSC65\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(225,5): error : Could not locate C:\Path\Common\packages.config.  Ensure that this project has Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and packages.config is located next to the project file.

That leads me to believe that the problem lies in that Bcl targets file, and it seems to be yelling about this line:

```
<ValidatePackageReferences Packages="@(ValidatePackages)"
                           ReferencingProject="$(BclBuildReferencingProject)"
                           ReferencingProjectPackagesConfig="$(BclBuildReferencingProjectConfig)"
                           ReferencedProject="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                           ReferencedProjectPackagesConfig="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.config"
                           TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)" />
```

"Website.ProjectSC65" has a reference to Common.SC65.

I have occasionally had weird problems with nuget packages acting funny, but I can't seem to shake this issue no matter what I do. Mostly some `Update-Package -reinstall` combination solves my issues. I need these different packages per project, as they support different versions of the framework.

I am fully aware that it is looking for a packages file that doesn't exist technically, as it should be referencing 'packages.Common.SC65.config'.

What's weirder still, *I can't find anything on the internet now* that references the above technique to reference project level dependencies. I know I found this at one point, but I have no idea if this is how it should be done.

So, the main things I need to know:

1. What could be causing the error above in my project build, and how
   would I fix it?
2. What is the **proper** way of setting up nuget packages
   on a **project level**? (not a solution level)

Comment: I think the message is telling you that it expects csproj and config to be at same directory level; yours is not.  I also think if you edit the csproj in an editor that you could change the config file path to point to where you actually have it.  I'm assuming that you have just moved things around from their original locations.

Comment: Oh, BTW, the "norm" would be that the csproj and config would be at exactly the same level.  That is how Visual Studio initially creates them.  But I don't believe this is absolutely required (I might be wrong about that).  If it's not required, you could just change the config path in csproj.

Comment: @jeffprince I'm sorry, that's more of a logical representation. It is all at the same level.

Comment: OK, so I think you should go to the root of your solution, find the packages directory at that level, and look at repositories.config file.  I suspect for each of your projects it is specify the wrong config file name.

Comment: @JeffPrince It seems right to me. The repositories.config file for my web project only references itself and packages.Common.SC65.config. The common library only references packages.Common.SCXX.config in all forms, and one packages.config from a library it depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it seems like that technique of including project level configuration isn't supported out of the box on *everything*.

In my web project, I took the `/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14/tools/Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets` file and modified the line it was complaining about.

```
<ValidatePackageReferences Packages="@(ValidatePackages)"
                           ReferencingProject="$(BclBuildReferencingProject)"
                           ReferencingProjectPackagesConfig="$(BclBuildReferencingProjectConfig)"
                           ReferencedProject="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                           ReferencedProjectPackagesConfig="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.config"
                           TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)" />
```

I did so by replacing this line:
`ReferencedProjectPackagesConfig="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.config"`

With this line:

```
ReferencedProjectPackagesConfig="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.$(MSBuildProjectName).config"
```

Injecting the project name into the property does work well. This may cause issues later if I have other nuget packages I'm referencing from other libraries higher up the chain that are simply "packages.config". For now though, this is a decent solution.

This feels really hacky though. **I'd love to hear other answers, especially ones that don't involve modifying the internals of a package.**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error on UWP project. And following below worked for me.

I did check and see the package.config in the right directory and I did have Microsoft.BCL.Build. The only way to get this to work is to close visual studio delete the obj folder in the solutions directory. Once the obj folder is deleted and I reloaded the project in visual studio everything worked again.

Source:
 http://onteorablog.azurewebsites.net/ensure-that-this-project-has-microsoft-bcl-build-installed-and-packages-config-is-located-next-to-the-project-file/

Comment: I feel like this solves a lot of issues with packages and versions. I really wish the "Clean Project" command did this automatically for us.

Comment: @WiteCastle it is unfortunately is the case for many other issues today. If you get a weird error, just delete bin, obj folders for both XF and Droid projects, clean temp folder. clean solution-rebuild. restart VS etc.