# Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct

Tags: build, msbuild, msbuild-task, nuget-package-restore

We have downloaded a project from TFS and after restoring Nuget packages we are getting below error:

```
Error   5   The "ValidatePackageReferences" task could not be loaded from the assembly projectPath\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///projectPath\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  projectName
```

We have not used Task anywhere.  It seems it is being used internally.  Any pointer how to get rid of this error?
Mostly it looks like its because of wrong version of NuGet package.  But not sure whats root cause.

We are using VS 2013 Update 5 version.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed project-specific nuget packages not being recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254228/installed-project-specific-nuget-packages-not-being-recognized)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it's a well known error for a specific package.

Answer (score 1):

First search "Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll." nuget on google. Then a link will be opened with named "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build/". Then copy the package name shown on the site like this

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build -Version 1.0.21
```

Then Open the Visual studio , Goto Tools>Nuget Package Manager>Package manager console. Now paste the copied install package,Install it. Then restart the VS.Issue will be solved.

Comment: Wanted to add that just restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me.

Comment: Simple Restart worked me aswell

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments by My Stack Overfloweth and Brendan Sluke upvoted by many should be one answer:

**Restart Visual Studio**.

That is how it worked instantly for my similar "Confirm that the  declaration is correct" error :

```
error MSB4062: The "Uno.Dsp.Tasks.GenerateFileTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:...\.nuget\packages\uno.dsp.tasks\1.2.7\build\../tools/Uno.Dsp.Tasks.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```